# FIPS mode in java11

Tags: java, bouncycastle, java-11, fips

Trying to list the bcfips provider getting

```
    java.util.ServiceConfigurationError: java.security.Provider: Provider org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider could not be instantiated
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader.fail(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$ProviderImpl.get(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.util.ServiceLoader$3.next(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$ProviderLoader.load(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig$3.run(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.doLoadProvider(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderConfig.getProvider(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.loadAll(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.ProviderList.removeInvalid(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/sun.security.jca.Providers.getFullProviderList(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.security.Security.getProviders(Unknown Source)
        at ListSecurityProviders.main(ListSecurityProviders.java:6)
    Caused by: org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsOperationError: Module checksum failed: unable to calculate
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.checksumValidate(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.crypto.fips.FipsStatus.isReady(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.getDefaultMode(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.crypto.CryptoServicesRegistrar.<clinit>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.ProvSecureHash$MD5.configure(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at org.bouncycastle.fips.core/org.bouncycastle.jcajce.provider.BouncyCastleFipsProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        ... 14 more
    scl:  getPermissions ProtectionDomain  (jrt:/java.security.jgss <no signer certificates>)
    jdk.internal.loader.ClassLoaders$PlatformClassLoader@7f13d6e
    <no principals>
    java.security.Permissions@51cdd8a (
    ("java.lang.RuntimePermission" "accessSystemModules"))
```

Followed the steps provided in the answer for same question asked [earlier](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57717503/globally-register-bouncycastle-security-provider-in-jdk-11).

Created jre using below command

```
./jlink --no-header-files --no-man-pages --compress=2 --strip-debug --module-path /root/bcjars/ --add-modules java.se,jdk    .unsupported,org.bouncycastle.fips.core --output /tmp/bcjdk/ --ignore-signing-information
```

jre created with below warning.

`WARNING: signed modular JAR /root/bcjars/bc-fips-1.0.2.4.jar is currently not supported`

After creating the jre, i can see the module in the --list-modules commnd.

```
   xx-xxx-xxxx:/tmp/bcjdk/bin # ./java --list-modules
    java.base@11.0.20
    java.compiler@11.0.20
    java.datatransfer@11.0.20
    java.desktop@11.0.20
    java.instrument@11.0.20
    java.logging@11.0.20
    java.management@11.0.20
    java.management.rmi@11.0.20
    java.naming@11.0.20
    java.net.http@11.0.20
    java.prefs@11.0.20
    java.rmi@11.0.20
    java.scripting@11.0.20
    java.se@11.0.20
    java.security.jgss@11.0.20
    java.security.sasl@11.0.20
    java.sql@11.0.20
    java.sql.rowset@11.0.20
    java.transaction.xa@11.0.20
    java.xml@11.0.20
    java.xml.crypto@11.0.20
    jdk.unsupported@11.0.20
    org.bouncycastle.fips.core
```

Program i ran to list the providers.

```
  import java.security.Provider;
    import java.security.Security;
    
    public class ListSecurityProviders {
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            Provider[] providers = Security.getProviders();
    
            for (Provider provider : providers) {
                System.out.println("Provider: " + provider.getName());
               for (Provider.Service service : provider.getServices()) {
                   System.out.println("  Algorithm: " + service.getAlgorithm());
               }
            }
        }
    }
```

From the error it looks like it is failing due no signing information but jlink cannot create jre with signing information.

Comment: Maybe this will help? [signed modular JAR with crypto provider cannot be linked into run-time image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50597926/signed-modular-jar-with-crypto-provider-cannot-be-linked-into-run-time-image)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I got a response from bouncy castle folks and seems like this is expected.